# Configure SQL PolyBase to access external data in MongoDB - problem

Tags: sql, mongodb, polybase, sql-server-2019

Im trying to connect SQL server using Polybase with MongoDB but Im failing to create the external data source for that. Please help ...

Im using the following code:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypassword';  

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MongoDbUser
WITH IDENTITY = 'myusername', Secret = 'thepassword';


CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE external_DS_MongoDB
WITH (
TYPE = HADOOP,
LOCATION = 'mongodb://localhost:27017', 
CREDENTIAL = MongoDbUser
);
```

Im expecting the create the datasource with name "external_DS_MongoDB" but Im facing the following error in SQL:

Msg 105007, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Scheme of the input URI is not supported. Please revise the following scheme and try again: 'mongodb'

Can anybody advice me ?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: Hello, Im using this version : Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (CTP2.2) - 15.0.1200.24 (X64)

Answer (score 2):

TYPE is not needed when creating a MongoDB data source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE external_DS_MongoDB
WITH 
(
LOCATION = 'mongodb://localhost:27017', 
CREDENTIAL = MongoDbUser
);
```

Comment: For future users, the topic is well documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-mongodb?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)